# How to handle empty values in BCP from csv to Sql table

Tags: sql

I have a csv file in below format. It uses (,) as a delimiter.

1,a,b

2,c,d,e,f

When I try to insert this into the sql with same table structure. I get the insert as below,

**ID | First Name | Last Name | Dept | Address**

1       a            b          2       c

d       e            f

But Actually I need the insert in the below format

**ID | First Name | Last Name | Dept | Address**

1       a            b

2       c            d          e        f

I am using BCP to insert into sql table. Kindly provide the terminator for achiving this. Thanks in advance.

Note: My format file is in xml format. It is in below format,

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to  pad each row on up to 5 fields, as SQL takes any delimiter isntead of a special one, so the `,` is a next field seperator to SQL in the same way as the the line break is.

so you had to do:

```
1,a,b,null,null

2,c,d,e,f
```

instead of:

```
1,a,b

2,c,d,e,f
```

Comment: Hi Zaibis,Thanks for your reply. Since I have thousand of rows, I cant check each rows seperatly, I cant do it manually. But the delimiter should identify the end of row automatically.

Comment: Hm then you could use on the one hand try to fix it with regex. But Thats not that good idea. What sql are you using? regulary linebreak should be a end of row seperator. Does your sql treat this diferent? Otherwise check the csv in a texteditor Maybe it uses a single `\r` as line break, while your sql database expects it to be a `\r`. To get mor precise you would have to add more informations. What OS are you on? What Database are you using? Does the linebreak work in diferent cases as row seperator? Did you check for the kind of linebreak character?

Comment: @PradheepHalan I found this in sql standard: `5.2 <token> and <separator>...Syntax Rules...4) <newline> is the implementation-defined end-of-line indicator.` So indeed the new line operator could be diferent depending on the sql implementation and Operating system you are working on. In other words: your csv could use a line break the document viewer you looked it at with was supporting, but your sql isn't acepting it and ignores its functionality as row seperator. Sounds quite unusal to me but it could be possible.